# How to find max value using RDD aggregate() and groupBy() in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to find the max value within an RDD for each country's total. For reference, the data I am using is in this format
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVU5P.png). I would like to solve this problem using `rdd.aggregate(zero, seqOp, combOp)` and `rdd.groupBy()` please, to better my understanding of how they work together.

I have been doing lots of trial and error with aggregate() but I can't understand how to formulate the lambda functions to work out the max values.